# Porque minha requisição ajax não está funcionando?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
         
          $('#enviar').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          data: '',
          url:'<?php echo base_url('admin/salvar_produto'); ?>',
          success: function(retorno){
          notify.showNotification('top','right')
        
      }
       })}
</script>
```

Comment: Está faltando o `echo` `<?php echo base_url('admin/salvar_produto'); ?>` ou foi erro de digitação na pergunta?

Comment: sim estava faltando ;) desatenção minha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma coisa que ajuda é identar o código

```
<script type="text/javascript">

          $('#enviar').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: '',
            url:'<?php base_url('admin/salvar_produto'); ?>',
            success: function(retorno){

              notify.showNotification('top','right')

            }
       })
 }/*faltou esse parenteses ->*/)
</script>
```